# Recieving the error "play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first" when the play() methodbeing executed by event listener

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

Getting the following error message despite requiring user input to trigger the play method for an Audio object. It does seem to start functioning but only after the second touch is made on the control element.

`script.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

**JS**

```
const control = document.querySelector(".control")
const audioElement = new Audio('Music/9oclock.mp3')
const playbtn = document.querySelector("#play")
const pausebtn = document.querySelector("#pause")

let playing = false;

control.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
    playMusic()
})

function playMusic() {

    if (playing) {

        playing = false;
        pauseAudio();
        playbtn.style.display = "block"
        pausebtn.style.display = "none"

    } else {

        playing = true;
        playAudio();
        playbtn.style.display = "none"
        pausebtn.style.display = "block"

    }

}

function playAudio() {
    audioElement.play();
}

function pauseAudio() {
    audioElement.pause();
}
```